# How to get data for past X weeks in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a below query which I run gives me the single count for previous week which is `Week 44`. Current week is 45 as of now.

```
with data_holder as
(
with tree_post as
(Select contractid as conid, max(goldennmber) as goldennmber
from zeus.user_keys_post group by contractid)
Select * from tree_post join zeus.user_keys_post b
on tree_post.conid = b.contractid and tree_post.goldennmber = b.goldennmber
),
 
name as 
(
SELECT abc, client_id, services from dim.crom c1 where c1.ver = (SELECT MAX(ver) from dim.crom c2 
where c1.client_id = c2.client_id)
)
 
select
count(distinct(clientid))
from data_holder
left join name
on name.client_id = data_holder.clientid
where POC NOT IN ('SGH', 'IKU')
and status IN ('NOTTAKEN')
and (fromWeek <= '44' AND toWeek >= '45')
```

As of now the output I see is this which is for Week 44-

```
Count
-----
124
```

Now I am trying to make this query dynamic such that it can give me count for past 6 weeks starting from 44 to 39 not including current week something like below as an output:

```
Count   Week
------------
124     W44
125     W43
126     W42
127     W41
128     W40
129     W39
```

So my condition for each week will be like this if I run it manually for each of those week -

```
and (fromWeek <= '44' AND toWeek >= '45') // for week 44
and (fromWeek <= '43' AND toWeek >= '44') // for week 43
and (fromWeek <= '42' AND toWeek >= '43') // for week 42
and (fromWeek <= '41' AND toWeek >= '42') // for week 41
and (fromWeek <= '40' AND toWeek >= '41') // for week 40
and (fromWeek <= '39' AND toWeek >= '40') // for week 39
```

Now I need to make above manual query for each of the week in a dynamic way. I came up with below query but somehow I don't get any output back when I run it. Anything wrong I am doing in below query?

```
with data_holder as
(
with tree_post as
(Select contractid as conid, max(goldennmber) as goldennmber
from zeus.user_keys_post group by contractid)
Select * from tree_post join zeus.user_keys_post b
on tree_post.conid = b.contractid and tree_post.goldennmber = b.goldennmber
),
 
name as 
(
SELECT abc, client_id, services from dim.crom c1 where c1.ver = (SELECT MAX(ver) from dim.crom c2 
where c1.client_id = c2.client_id)
)

select fromWeek,
count(distinct(clientid))
from data_holder
left join name
on name.client_id = data_holder.clientid
where POC NOT IN ('SGH', 'IKU')
and status IN ('NOTTAKEN')
and fromWeek <= date_part(w, current_date - interval '6 weeks') 
and toWeek >= date_part(w, current_date)
group by fromWeek
```

**Note:**

`fromWeek` and `toWeek` column are integer data type and they contain week number just fyi. It's a legacy query so I am trying to make it dynamic. Not sure why they have single quotes around 44 and 45 but If I run my original manual query like this `and (fromWeek <= '44' AND toWeek >= '45')` or this `and (fromWeek <= 44 AND toWeek >= 45)` for week 44 I always get same data as 124.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: It doesn't give me anything back as I mentioned above. Am I doing anything wrong in my dynamic query?

Comment: how is `fromWeek` and `toWeek` defined? I don't understand this expression `(fromWeek <= '44' AND toWeek >= '45')`

Comment: I updated my question. They are integer data types and since it's a legacy query so trying to make it dynamic. Not sure why they have single quotes around 44 and 45 but If I run my original manual query like this `and (fromWeek <= '44' AND toWeek >= '45')` or this `and (fromWeek <= 44 AND toWeek >= 45)` for week 44 I always get same data as 124.

Comment: I don't understand how these two columns work together, `fromWeek <= '44'` means fromWeek could be anything between 0 and 44 and `AND toWeek >= 45` means it could be anything larger or equal to 45.  Why does this exactly define week 44?

Comment: I am not sure on that either but this is something we have been using from quite some time as it's a legacy query so I was trying to adapt this manual query to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want toWeek to be 1 greater than fromWeek?  If so your where clauses should be:

```
...
and fromWeek <= date_part(w, current_date - interval '6 weeks') 
and toWeek >= date_part(w, current_date - interval '5 weeks')
...
```

I suspect you just don't have data for values for toWeek that are high enough to pass your toWeek where clause.